# How to concatenate number and string for datetime analysis in Kusto (KQL)?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitor

I'm trying to set some parameters in an Azure Workbook.

For some reason, I can't concatenate two values to create some dynamic date filters.

**I've tried:**

- `'{LogBuffer}' + '{LogBufferUnits}'`
- `{LogBuffer} + '{LogBufferUnits}'`
- `strcat('{LogBuffer}', '{LogBufferUnits}')`

**All of these fail with some form of:**

[image]

**This works, so I know that it can be done:**

[image]

---

**EDIT 1:**
You're right...

At first, this worked...
[image]

Then per your comment, realized I didn't need `totimespan()`; simplified down to...
[image]

Comment: In the same manner, no need for `todatetime()` when a datetime literal could be used e.g., `datetime({Timestamp})` or `datetime("{Timestamp}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually simpler than you think:

```
print {LogBuffer}{LogBufferUnits}
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 00:10:00 |

Workbook parameters are nothing more than textual placeholders, replaced pre-execution, with the supplied values.

This is what your code looked like after the parameters were set:

```
print '10' + 'm'
```

> Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between StringBuffer and
> StringBuffer

```
print 10 + 'm'
```

> Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between I64 and
> StringBuffer

This following code is valid, however the result is a string

```
print strcat('10', 'm')
```

Therefore, the following code is invalid

```
print now() - strcat('10', 'm')
```

> Arithmetic expression cannot be carried-out between DateTime and
> StringBuffer

This would have worked:

```
print now() - totimespan(strcat('10', 'm'))
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 2022-09-23T05:37:33.726665Z |

Comment: Thank you! `totimespan()` is what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Why not use the 1st option?

Comment: You're right! See **Edit 1:**.